# Pantheon-files: network server not showing after reboot

Tags: pantheon

I can add my network server (secure webDAV) in pantheon-files, but it isn't there after reboot.

How am I able to achieve this? And why isn't this an option by default?

I know about davfs2 but I was hoping it can achieved without other software, scripts are fine.

I am running fully updated elementary OS, dual boot with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround to elementary OS not auto-mounting the webDAV server using Pantheon file browser:

1. Create root folder on server containing all data.
2. Bookmark root folder in the file browser.
3. WebDAV server is automatically connected on first use of the bookmark after reboot.

I am still looking for a better solution. But anyway, this way I work around the issue that I was not able to bookmark the webDAV server itself in Pantheon.